# Definitions of the ring $R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty)$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring, and let $I = (x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ be a finitely-generated ideal inside of $R$, generated by a regular sequence.

In algebraic topology one often encounters a ring, usually denoted $R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty)$ , defined in the following way, by first inverting $x_i$ and taking the cokernel, i.e., by the short exact sequences
$$
0 \to R \to x_0^{-1}R \to R/(x_0^\infty) \to 0 \\
0 \to R/(x_0^\infty) \to x_1^{-1}R/(x_0^\infty) \to R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty) \to 0 \\
0 \to R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty) \to x_2^{-1}R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty) \to R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty,x_2^\infty) \to 0 \\
 \cdots
$$

I would like to propose a different construction. Let $I^k$ denote the $k$-th power of the ideal $I$. There is a system
$$
\cdots \subset I^k \subset I^{k-1} \subset \cdots 
$$
which gives maps
$$
\cdots \to R/I^k \to R/I^{k-1} \to \cdots 
$$

Now we work in the derived category, and let $DM = \mathbb{R}\text{Hom}_R(M,R)$ be the (derived) dual. The first claim is that $DR/I^k = \Sigma^{-n}R/I^k$. To see this, start with the cofiber sequence
$$
R \xrightarrow{x_0} R \to R/(x_0);
$$
this is self dual, and $DR/x_0 = \Sigma^{-1}R/(x_1)$. Induction using the cofiber sequences
$$
R/(x_0,\ldots,x_{i-1}) \xrightarrow{x_i} R/(x_0,\ldots,x_{i-1}) \to R/(x_0,\ldots,x_i)
$$
proves the claim for $R/I$. For $R/I^k$ inductively use the cofiber sequences
$$
I^k/I^{k-1} \to R/I^k \to R/I^{k-1}
$$
and the fact that 
$$
\bigoplus_{k \ge 0} I^k/I^{k+1} = R/I[x_1,\ldots,x_n]
$$
to see inductively that $DR/I^k = \Sigma^{-n}R/I^k$.

Thus we can get a sequence
$$
\cdots \to R/I^{k-1} \to R/I^k \to \cdots.
$$

Define $R/I^\infty$ to be the colimit of this system.

> > Is $R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty) \simeq R/I^\infty$?

Here is an idea of how to prove this. Firstly, I believe one can show, by a cofinality argument, that
$$
R/I^\infty = \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{n-1}^i).
$$

(Here I mean the colimit over the system of ideals  $I_t = (x_0^t,\ldots,x_{n-1}^t)$).

Then to prove the claim note that it is clear that $R/(x_1^\infty) = \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i)$. Then inductively we have
$$
R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{k}^\infty )= \operatorname{colim}_j(R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{k-1}^\infty)/x_k^j) \\
= \operatorname{colim}_j(\operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{k-1}^i)/x_k^j) \\
= \operatorname{colim}_j \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{k-1}^i,x_k^j) \\
= \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{k-1}^i,x_k^i)
$$

By induction this should give the result, I hope.

Comment: I don't see any question.

Comment: @Crostul: It's about half-way down. Is $R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty) \simeq R/I^\infty$? The rest is an attempt at a proof, but I'm not sure if it is correct!